# How can i stop the troubleshot of updating the pics in vs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

i have a file assets in visual studio when i upload photos. when i try to connect them with a code frame i need to restart it in order to make the image appear even tho i can see it in assets. whats the matter

I restarted it but it still takes a lot from my time to solve it and as a result i can't code well.